# JPA Unknown mappedBy in: ServiceContract.serviceLocation, referenced property unknown:ServiceLocation.service_contract

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Below is my ServiceContract.java

```
package com.cerebro.model.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "service_contract")
public class ServiceContract extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Identifiable<Long>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServiceContract.class.getName());

    // Raw attributes
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String type;
    private Long contractStart;
    private Long contractEnd;
    private Boolean isrepeated;
    private Boolean autoApproved;
    private Boolean staffAutoApproved;
    private String status;

    // Many to one
    private HospitalUnit unit;
    private Staff preferredStaff;
    private Specialty specialty;
    private SkillMaster skill;

    private ServiceLocation ServiceLocation;
    private ServiceSchedule ServiceSchedule;
    private Hospital hospital;

    @Override
    public String entityClassName() {
        return ServiceContract.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    // -- [id] ------------------------

    @Override
    @Column(name = "id", precision = 19)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "service_contract_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "service_contract_id_seq", sequenceName = "service_contract_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ServiceContract id(Long id) {
        setId(id);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isIdSet() {
        return id != null;
    }
    // -- [name] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 256)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ServiceContract name(String name) {
        setName(name);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [description] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, length = 500)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public ServiceContract description(String description) {
        setDescription(description);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [type] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "`type`", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ServiceContract type(String type) {
        setType(type);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [contractStart] ------------------------

    @Digits(integer = 19, fraction = 0)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "contract_start", nullable = false, precision = 19)
    public Long getContractStart() {
        return contractStart;
    }

    public void setContractStart(Long contractStart) {
        this.contractStart = contractStart;
    }

    public ServiceContract contractStart(Long contractStart) {
        setContractStart(contractStart);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [contractEnd] ------------------------

    @Digits(integer = 19, fraction = 0)
    @Column(name = "contract_end", precision = 19)
    public Long getContractEnd() {
        return contractEnd;
    }

    public void setContractEnd(Long contractEnd) {
        this.contractEnd = contractEnd;
    }

    public ServiceContract contractEnd(Long contractEnd) {
        setContractEnd(contractEnd);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [isrepeated] ------------------------

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "isrepeated", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public Boolean getIsrepeated() {
        return isrepeated;
    }

    public void setIsrepeated(Boolean isrepeated) {
        this.isrepeated = isrepeated;
    }

    public ServiceContract isrepeated(Boolean isrepeated) {
        setIsrepeated(isrepeated);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [autoApproved] ------------------------

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "auto_approved", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public Boolean getAutoApproved() {
        return autoApproved;
    }

    public void setAutoApproved(Boolean autoApproved) {
        this.autoApproved = autoApproved;
    }

    public ServiceContract autoApproved(Boolean autoApproved) {
        setAutoApproved(autoApproved);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [staffAutoApproved] ------------------------

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "staff_auto_approved", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public Boolean getStaffAutoApproved() {
        return staffAutoApproved;
    }

    public void setStaffAutoApproved(Boolean staffAutoApproved) {
        this.staffAutoApproved = staffAutoApproved;
    }

    public ServiceContract staffAutoApproved(Boolean staffAutoApproved) {
        setStaffAutoApproved(staffAutoApproved);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [createdts] ------------------------

    public ServiceContract createdts(Long createdts) {
        setCreatedts(createdts);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [updatedts] ------------------------

    public ServiceContract updatedts(Long updatedts) {
        setUpdatedts(updatedts);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [createdby] ------------------------

    public ServiceContract createdby(String createdby) {
        setCreatedby(createdby);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [status] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 2147483647)
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public ServiceContract status(String status) {
        setStatus(status);
        return this;
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Many to One support
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // many-to-one: ServiceContract.unit ==> HospitalUnit.id
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    public HospitalUnit getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link #unit} without adding this ServiceContract instance on the
     * passed {@link #unit}
     */
    public void setUnit(HospitalUnit unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public ServiceContract unit(HospitalUnit unit) {
        setUnit(unit);
        return this;
    }

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // many-to-one: ServiceContract.preferredStaff ==> Staff.id
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    @JoinColumn(name = "preferred_staff_id")
    @ManyToOne
    public Staff getPreferredStaff() {
        return preferredStaff;
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link #preferredStaff} without adding this ServiceContract
     * instance on the passed {@link #preferredStaff}
     */
    public void setPreferredStaff(Staff preferredStaff) {
        this.preferredStaff = preferredStaff;
    }

    public ServiceContract preferredStaff(Staff preferredStaff) {
        setPreferredStaff(preferredStaff);
        return this;
    }

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // many-to-one: ServiceContract.specialty ==> Specialty.id
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "specialty_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    public Specialty getSpecialty() {
        return specialty;
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link #specialty} without adding this ServiceContract instance
     * on the passed {@link #specialty}
     */
    public void setSpecialty(Specialty specialty) {
        this.specialty = specialty;
    }

    public ServiceContract specialty(Specialty specialty) {
        setSpecialty(specialty);
        return this;
    }

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // many-to-one: ServiceContract.skill ==> SkillMaster.id
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    public SkillMaster getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link #skill} without adding this ServiceContract instance on
     * the passed {@link #skill}
     */
    public void setSkill(SkillMaster skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public ServiceContract skill(SkillMaster skill) {
        setSkill(skill);
        return this;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "ServiceContract", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public ServiceLocation getServiceLocation() {
        return ServiceLocation;
    }

    public void setServiceLocation(ServiceLocation ServiceLocation) {
        this.ServiceLocation = ServiceLocation;
    }

    public ServiceContract serviceLocation(ServiceLocation ServiceLocation) {
        setServiceLocation(ServiceLocation);
        return this;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "ServiceContract", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public ServiceSchedule getServiceSchedule() {
        return ServiceSchedule;
    }

    public void setServiceSchedule(ServiceSchedule ServiceSchedule) {
        this.ServiceSchedule = ServiceSchedule;
    }

    public ServiceContract serviceSchedule(ServiceSchedule ServiceSchedule) {
        setServiceSchedule(ServiceSchedule);
        return this;
    }

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "hospital_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne
    public Hospital getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }

    public void setHospital(Hospital hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

    public ServiceContract hospital(Hospital hospital) {
        setHospital(hospital);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the default values.
     */
    public ServiceContract withDefaults() {
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Equals implementation using a business key.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return this == other || (other instanceof ServiceContract && hashCode() == other.hashCode());
    }

    private IdentifiableHashBuilder identifiableHashBuilder = new IdentifiableHashBuilder();

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return identifiableHashBuilder.hash(log, this);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a readable string representation for this ServiceContract
     * instance.
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this) //
                .add("id", getId()) //
                .add("name", getName()) //
                .add("description", getDescription()) //
                .add("type", getType()) //
                .add("contractStart", getContractStart()) //
                .add("contractEnd", getContractEnd()) //
                .add("isrepeated", getIsrepeated()) //
                .add("autoApproved", getAutoApproved()) //
                .add("staffAutoApproved", getStaffAutoApproved()) //
                .add("createdts", getCreatedts()) //
                .add("updatedts", getUpdatedts()) //
                .add("createdby", getCreatedby()) //
                .add("status", getStatus()) //
                .toString();
    }
}
```

And ServiceLocation.java

```
package com.cerebro.model.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "service_location")
public class ServiceLocation extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Identifiable<Long>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServiceLocation.class.getName());

    // Raw attributes
    private Long id;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String country;

    // Many to one
    private ServiceContract ServiceContract;

    @Override
    public String entityClassName() {
        return ServiceLocation.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    // -- [id] ------------------------

    @Override
    @Column(name = "id", precision = 19)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "service_location_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "service_location_id_seq", sequenceName = "service_location_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ServiceLocation id(Long id) {
        setId(id);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isIdSet() {
        return id != null;
    }
    // -- [address1] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "address1", nullable = false, length = 500)
    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public ServiceLocation address1(String address1) {
        setAddress1(address1);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [address2] ------------------------

    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "address2", length = 500)
    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public ServiceLocation address2(String address2) {
        setAddress2(address2);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [city] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public ServiceLocation city(String city) {
        setCity(city);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [state] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "`state`", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public ServiceLocation state(String state) {
        setState(state);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [zip] ------------------------

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "zip", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public ServiceLocation zip(String zip) {
        setZip(zip);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [country] ------------------------

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "country", length = 50)
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public ServiceLocation country(String country) {
        setCountry(country);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [createdts] ------------------------


    public ServiceLocation createdts(Long createdts) {
        setCreatedts(createdts);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [updatedts] ------------------------

    public ServiceLocation updatedts(Long updatedts) {
        setUpdatedts(updatedts);
        return this;
    }
    // -- [createdby] ------------------------

    public ServiceLocation createdby(String createdby) {
        setCreatedby(createdby);
        return this;
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Many to One support
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // many-to-one: ServiceLocation.serviceContract ==> ServiceContract.id
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

//    @NotNull
//    @JoinColumn(name = "service_contract_id", nullable = false)
//    @ManyToOne
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_contract_id")
    public ServiceContract getServiceContract() {
        return ServiceContract;
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link #serviceContract} without adding this ServiceLocation instance on the passed {@link #serviceContract}
     */
    public void setServiceContract(ServiceContract ServiceContract) {
        this.ServiceContract = ServiceContract;
    }

    public ServiceLocation serviceContract(ServiceContract ServiceContract) {
        setServiceContract(ServiceContract);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the default values.
     */
    public ServiceLocation withDefaults() {
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Equals implementation using a business key.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return this == other || (other instanceof ServiceLocation && hashCode() == other.hashCode());
    }

    private IdentifiableHashBuilder identifiableHashBuilder = new IdentifiableHashBuilder();

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return identifiableHashBuilder.hash(log, this);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a readable string representation for this ServiceLocation instance.
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this) //
                .add("id", getId()) //
                .add("address1", getAddress1()) //
                .add("address2", getAddress2()) //
                .add("city", getCity()) //
                .add("state", getState()) //
                .add("zip", getZip()) //
                .add("country", getCountry()) //
                .add("createdts", getCreatedts()) //
                .add("updatedts", getUpdatedts()) //
                .add("createdby", getCreatedby()) //
                .toString();
    }
}
```

When I deploy, I keep getting Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.cerebro.model.domain.ServiceContract.serviceLocation, referenced property unknown:com.cerebro.model.domain.ServiceLocation.service_contract
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `mappedBy` property name should begin with a lowercase `'s'`:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "serviceContract", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
public ServiceLocation getServiceLocation() {
    return ServiceLocation;
}
```

Even though the name of field `ServiceLocation.ServiceContract` begins with a uppercase `'S'`, you are annotating the getter method and the JPA spec indicates that the property name is to be derived from a getter method name using the JavaBean convention (i.e. strip off the `'get'` from the method name and convert the first character to lowercase, unless it is followed by yet another uppercase letter).